# merging almost identical row in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a large data frame of clinical data (882 obs of 154 variables). In this data frame there are 441 unique patients, repeated twice, except for one column. So a dummy version of the table looks like this:

| id | age | gender | tumour | type | treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 76 | F | colon | adeno | radiotherapy |
| 1 | 76 | F | colon | adeno | chemotherapy |
| 2 | 70 | M | colon | adeno | radiotherapy |
| 2 | 70 | M | colon | adeno | chemotherapy |
| 3 | 68 | M | colon | adeno | radiotherapy |
| 3 | 68 | M | colon | adeno | chemotherapy |

I'd like to condense this table to look like this:

| id | age | gender | tumour | type | treatment_a | treatment_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 76 | F | colon | adeno | radiotherapy | chemotherapy |
| 2 | 70 | M | colon | adeno | radiotherapy | chemotherapy |
| 3 | 68 | M | colon | adeno | radiotherapy | chemotherapy |

I've looked online and tried using solutions to similar problems, eg. `sapply`, `group_by`, `summarise`, and `distinct` but I just can't seem to get the syntax right.
I'm a total novice at this and this seems like such a simple problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check out https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you can add a reproducible example with a few lines of your data, e.g. using `dput()`, then it'll be easier to help you out - in this case copying from your table also works though.

You could try using `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package. Assuming your data is called `df` and is a tibble:

We first use `pivot_wider()` and then rename the column names to get what you are looiking for

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, age, gender, tumour),values_from = treatment, names_from = treatment) %>%
  rename(treatment_a = radiotherapy, treatment_b=chemotherapy)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id   age gender tumour treatment_a   treatment_b  
  <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>        <chr>       
1     1    76 F      colon  radiotherapy chemotherapy
2     2    70 M      colon  radiotherapy chemotherapy
3     3    68 M      colon  radiotherapy chemotherapy
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll make sure to ask the question using ```dput()``` in the future. The answer worked perfectly as well.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option using `dcast`

```
dcast(
  setDT(df)[,q := paste0(treatment,"_",head(letters,.N)),id:type],
  ...~ q, 
  value.var = "treatment")
```

gives

```
   id age gender tumour  type chemotherapy_b radiotherapy_a
1:  1  76      F  colon adeno   chemotherapy   radiotherapy
2:  2  70      M  colon adeno   chemotherapy   radiotherapy
3:  3  68      M  colon adeno   chemotherapy   radiotherapy
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), age = c(76L, 76L, 
70L, 70L, 68L, 68L), gender = c("F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M"), 
    tumour = c("colon", "colon", "colon", "colon", "colon", "colon"
    ), type = c("adeno", "adeno", "adeno", "adeno", "adeno", 
    "adeno"), treatment = c("radiotherapy", "chemotherapy", "radiotherapy", 
    "chemotherapy", "radiotherapy", "chemotherapy")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: These packages are perfect for what I'm trying to do, don't know why I couldn't find them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
df=read.table(text="
id  age gender  tumour  type    treatment
1   76  F   colon   adeno   radiotherapy
1   76  F   colon   adeno   chemotherapy
2   70  M   colon   adeno   radiotherapy
2   70  M   colon   adeno   chemotherapy
3   68  M   colon   adeno   radiotherapy
3   68  M   colon   adeno   chemotherapy",h=T)

df$idontknow=ifelse(df$treatment=="radiotherapy","treatment_a","treatment_b")

library(reshape2)
dcast(df,id+age+gender+tumour+type~idontknow,value.var="treatment")

   id age gender tumour  type  treatment_a  treatment_b
1:  1  76      F  colon adeno radiotherapy chemotherapy
2:  2  70      M  colon adeno radiotherapy chemotherapy
3:  3  68      M  colon adeno radiotherapy chemotherapy
```